# Is there Substr oracle equivalent function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

The following statement in Pyspark is throwing an issue
        .select ('Substr(trim(Name), -3))')

```
    .select ('Substr(trim(Name), -3))')

     .select ('Substr(trim(Name), -3))')
```

The input data is RAMS 123 & expected output is 123

Answer (score 0):

[substr()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.Column.substr) method available in pyspark.

```
myDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Alex',"30"),("Hitesh R","34"),("David B","35")],("Name","Age"))

myDf.show()

+--------+---+
|    Name|Age|
+--------+---+
|    Alex| 30|
|Hitesh R| 34|
| David B| 35|
+--------+---+

myDf.select(myDf['Name'].substr(-3,3)).show()

+----------------------+                                                        
|substring(Name, -3, 3)|
+----------------------+
|                   lex|
|                   h R|
|                   d B|
+----------------------+
```